# possibilities of sorting m cubes into 3 boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have m similar cubes, and want to put them in 3 boxes.
How many possibilities do exist?

**Example**, If I have **2** cubes the answer is **6**.

```
**,  ,
  ,**,
  ,  ,**
* ,* ,
  ,* ,*
* ,  ,*
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your pictoral approach. You might notice that in each picture, you have four symbols: 2 `*` and 2 `,`. Any arrangement of these symbols gives a way of putting 2 cubes into 3 boxes. So you want to count the number of arrangements of these symbols.

One way of thinking of this is to think of you have four slots, and you need to choose two of them to be `,`. This forces the other two to be `*`. So how many ways can you choose 2 slots from a total of 4 slots? This is a combination,
$$ {4 \choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!} = \frac{4!}{2!2!} = \frac{24}{4} = 6.$$

If you have $m$ cubes and three boxes, then your diagrams would have $m$ `*` symbols and 2 `,` symbols. Any arrangement would correspond to a way of putting $m$ cubes into 3 boxes. And one way to count these would be to count how many ways there are to choose $2$ slots out of the total of $m + 2$, which is
$$ {m + 2\choose 2}.$$

Comment: Thanks! this was perfectly explained!

Comment: may you kindly help with this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617337/number-of-possibilities-to-interview-students