# number of possibilities to interview students

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

One semester includes **13** weeks, Given **8** students we want to interview them with the following conditions:

**1)** Each student should be interviewed at least once.

**2)** None can be interviewed more than 3 times (3 is the maximum).

Calculate the number of possibilities to interview the students.

*Note: As usual, the order of interviews matters so interviewing A at the first week and B at the second is not the same as interviewing B at the first and A at the second week.*

Comment: Only one student can be interviewed in one week?

Comment: yes, only one per week. In total there are 13 interviews

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Split by cases.

> Each student has to be interviewed once, so how can the remaining 5 interviews be done? It has to be either $1+1+1+1+1$, $1+1+1+2$, or $1+2+2$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I thought about your solution before but it doesn't work, for example how could we count all the inner orders of the first solution?

Comment: I think I got a potential answer can you check it for me?

Comment: Post your answer, and the community can help to review it.

Comment: I did post it as an answer

Comment: can u kindly review it? I have no time left

Answer (score -1):

After getting Hint here's my suggested answer, hope someone can review it:

[image]

Comment: The ${8 \choose 5 } $ coefficient is correct, but the number of ways to arrange should be ${13 \choose 2} {11 \choose 2 } { 9 \choose 2 } { 7 \choose 2 } { 5 \choose 2 } \times {3 \choose 1 } {2 \choose 1 } { 1 \choose 1}$. Do you see why?

Comment: why it's incorrect? for the first option we need to choose 5 from 8

Comment: Suppose we have chosen the 5 students to be $a, b, c, d, e$. How many ways are there to permute $a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, e, e, f, g, h$?

Comment: 13!/10 (I even tried this on simple example)

Comment: Would you say that the number of ways to permute $a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, f, g, h$ is also equal to $13!/10$? (I'm guessing based on how you set it up).

Comment: I got the 10 from counting every letter that appears more than one time

Comment: See my previous comment. Are there the same number of ways to permute both (multi-)sets?

Comment: try it on simple example you will see it's correct

Comment: It is true for simple cases like $\{a, a, b, b, c\}$, because you are dividing by $ 4 = 2^2$. It is not true for cases like $\{ a, a, b, b, c, c, d \}$ or $\{a, a, a, b, b, c\}$ or $\{a, a, a, b, b, b, c \}$. I'm exiting this conversation.

Comment: according to my solution for {,,,,,,}  there are 7 possibilities and if you check it you will see it's correct. But you said mine doesn't work on this case....

Comment: aabbccd, aabbcdc, aabbdcc, aabdbcc, aadbbcc, adabbcc, daabbcc are already 7 possibilities, and I haven't permuted $a,b,c$ as yet. Besides, your way will give $7!/6$ (assuming it is "total number of terms factorial / total number of duplicated terms".)

Comment: so can u suggest final answer to this problem?

Comment: Coming back to my very first comment on your solution ... Do you see why?